# Update a table based on PIVOT table data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have two tables called "User" and "userAudit".

So I am using following query to generate a PIVOT table from Audit table along with field and respective data:

@Cols is dynamic length, it may have two or three columns or any number of columns with comma seperated.

So I am using this query to generate dynamic PIVOT table as:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName
1            xxx
```

`And my selct * from User`

gives me as

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName
1            asdf       qwer
```

But I need output as

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName
1            xxx        qwer
```

This means I need to update the modified value fields updated from that PIVOT table 
when I am selecting final output

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

                    set @cols = 'EmployeeID, FirstName';

                    SET @query = @query + 
                                    ' SELECT DISTINCT p.*
                                      FROM 
                                     (
                                        select
                                          e.UserID,
                                          e.FieldName,

                                            (' <Some dynamic Queries to run> ') As Data

                                            FROM temp e
                                            ) x
                                            pivot 
                                            (
                                                max(DATA)
                                                for FieldName in (' + @cols + ')
                                            ) p'


                 EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

EDIT:

My UserAudit table as follows:

```
UserID    ModifiedColumnName    PreviuosData   UpdatedData   Date
1             FirstName           XXX              asdf      12/01/2014
```

User Table:

```
UserID   FirstName    LAstName   Address                 date
1         asdf         qwer        wretwertwerter        12/03/2014
```

So whenever I am updating this user table I am recording which field is modified and what are the values before and after modified and on which date.

So when i need to know how user data looked like on perticular date(ex: on 12/01/2014) then I will loop through the Audit table find which are the fields i have to select(Like FistName name in the above case) and read appropriate value (Means read "previousData" field value) and return it along with other user table data).

```
UserID  FirstName   LastName    Address   
    1          xxx        qwer       wretwertwerter
```

Thanks

Comment: It might be easier to show your table structures (both tables), some sample data and the final desired result.  You can easily build the list of columns by querying the data the tables, but right now it's not exactly clear what you are asking.

Comment: Do you think that edited part is clear?